# Android okhttp measure HTTP setup time for every request

Tags: android, tcp, okhttp

I am developing an Android app and I need to measure the connection setup time. Basically it is the tcp connection time. Is it possible to do this with OKHTTP?

Answer (score 2):

The connection is established between the last application interceptor and the first network interceptor. You could probably set up a pair of [interceptors](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors) to take the measurement.